# How to fix "K3b can only copy CD-Extra mixed mode CDs" error?

Tags: backup, iso, k3b

I'm trying to make a backup (an iso image) of an old cd, but I'm getting the error message "K3b can only copy CD-Extra mixed mode CDs", any idea how to fix it?

I saw in a forum telling to check the missing programs on the configurations, but nothing is missing now and I'm still getting this error.

Using K3B 2.0.2, and Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an ISO because they only store a single track, and mixed CD's have multiple tracks. Instead, you have to clone the CD. To do this in K3b, first click Copy CD; then on the Options tab, change Copy Mode to **Clone Copy**. Then copy the CD like normal.

[image: Screenshot showing changing Copy Mode to CLone Copy in K3b]

K3b should also create a TOC file to go along with the CD image. K3b can then use both of those files to burn a copy of the original CD.

Answer (score 1):

When searching with the "K3b can only copy CD-Extra mixed mode CDs". One of the hits is the: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.k3b/4103:

A question:

> what kind of cd is it ?

A guess:

> ...this very much looks like a copyprotected cd that doesn't obey the
>   cd standards. i strongly suspect it's some windows programme, so you'd
>   be best off to try your luck with some windows tool to nail that
>   sucker...

Something to try:

> Put the master disk in Start K3b Use the copy CD(or DVD) tool On
>   Options select "Only create image" On Image enter path info and a file
>   name for the new image On Advanced check the "Ignore  read errors" box
>   Then select start

Comment: The guess is right, the something to try didn't work. I'll try with Nero on Windows...